# JMeter Correlation: Why extracted value is not passed to next request during high volume testing say -1000 Threads

Tags: jmeter

I have extracted the value from the response and passing it through the next request. When I perform the test with minimum users e.g. up to 100 to 200 extracted values are passed to the next request properly. but during the scaling up the load to 500 to 1000, the variable name displayed as is in the request, not the extracted value. what would the reason and how to handle this?. because of this I am getting 502 bad gateway error.

Answer (score 0):

If JMeter fails to extract the value from the response most probably it means that there is no value in the response, my expectation is that under the load your application fails to respond properly therefore extraction fails.

502 bad gateway error doesn't have anything in common with the variable extraction, it indicates that your application is experiencing issues under the load

with regards to "how to handle this" - store the response data for the previous sampler, it can be done by adding [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) as a child of that sampler, this way you will be able to inspect the output and figure out what's wrong with it.

[image]

[image]

If you want to save response data for all samplers - move the listener to the same level as the samplers or above, see [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual chapter for more details.

Alternatively you can add next lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: So, Do I need to wait till the response received for the request, Then proceed with the next request?  Also, I would like to know How to calculate the total execution time to get the response for all the requests(total 100 requests) with the user load of 2000. sometimes transactions are missed out and again I need to increase the time period.